# Error resolving getLayoutInflater (not defined)

Tags: android

While am compiling the program with the below code, an error is occurring. It says getLayoutInflater ( ) is undefined. How can I resolve it?

```
 final LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater ( );
```

Comment: Put some source code and the error log

Comment: Stupid question, but. Did you forget to extend `Activity` class? Also, more code would be nice.

Comment: try to accept satisfactory answer. It will increase chances somebody will reply to your future questions, it will help whole community as well.

Answer (score 18):

HI Prasanth, you can try this

Step 1: Create a object for Layout Inflater as shown here:

```
LayoutInflater mInflater;
```

Step2: Intialize by passing Context

```
Context context=MyActivity.getApplicationContext();
mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
```

Step3: In get View meythod, you can intalize the view as

```
public View getView(int arg0, View myView, ViewGroup parent) {


            if (convertView == null) {

myView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.mytest, null);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Afaik the getLayoutInflater() is a method provided by Context. If this line is located in a class which doesn't inherit from Context this won't work. Pass it a Context object and call the method on this object.

Edit: I'm sorry, had a look at the api docs, it's provided by [Activity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#getLayoutInflater%28%29)

Answer (score 1):

This is what works for me :
In my activity code, I pass the context as a parameter to my adapter like this :

```
CustumAdapter myAdapter = new CustumAdapter(this, Items);
```

then I can use it in my adapter like this :

```
public class CustumAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

ArrayList<ListItem> Items ;
public Context context;

public CustumAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<ListItem> Items) {
    this.Items = Items;
    this.context = context;
}
....
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {        
    LayoutInflater myInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    View myview = myInflater.inflate(R.layout.row_item,null);
```

All works fine :)

Answer (score 0):

```
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
```